# regex python разбить

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, с регулярным выражением на python3

```
`\s0\s|\d{5}|\d\s?\d+\s\d{3}`
```

регулярка не может увидеть числа выделенные жирным шрифтом. Мне надо разбить цифры на 3 группы.

Смысл групп заключается в следующем

- 1. 3цифры 3цифры (6 символов, пример 494 870 )
- 2. 1цифра 3цифры 3цифры (7 символов 7 771 007)
- 3. 4цифры 3 цифры (7 символов 1994 450)
- 4. 5 цифр (23566, 30 773)
- 5. 0 надо всегда читать отдельно и в начале и в середине и в конце, смог сделать только в начале а второй ноль не цепляет отдельно.

---

```
494 870 427 273 344 980',
265 680 123 855 167 728',
191 339 449 948 624 938',
227 801 258 836 259 491',
7 771 007 6 628 770 6 753 741',
9 337 358 8 111 380 8 435 255',
3 602 396 1994 450 2370 625',
7530 040 6 383 292 6 567 057',
7032 611 6 181 052 6 416 880',
2854 194 3662 190 3501 212',
23566 39 439 43 890',
30 773 26 133 27 671',
156 560 74 784 75 941',
0 0 74431',
0 56 823 52 626',
18 478 4208 18 787',
8 769 5 186 6653',
```

Вот ссылка: [https://regex101.com/r/T0LjBe/1][1]

Благодарен за любую помощь, Спасибо!!!

Comment: Вы хотите найти `420`, но это всего лишь 3 цифры. Может, вам всё-таки подойдёт `\b(?:0|\d{5}|(?:\d ?)?\d+ \d{3})\b`? https://regex101.com/r/ViTJwa/1. Непонятно, почему у вас в выражении `\d+`, тогда как в требованиях нет упоминания об одной и более цифр в шаблоне.

Comment: Уважаемый Админ, как можно получить ответ, мне очень важен результат, Спасибо. Если написал не там прошу прощения

Comment: Это вы к кому обращаетесь? Нет тут "админов", это не форум. Я же вас просил уточнить требования, ответа вы не дали. Как вам помочь - неизвестно. `5 186 6653` - это потому что `(?:\d ?)?\d+ \d{3,4}` его находит.

Comment: Попробуйте https://regex101.com/r/ViTJwa/2

Comment: Сначала скажите, https://regex101.com/r/ViTJwa/2 работает как надо?

Comment: Работает, как надо, спасибо большое, я только не понял как можно благодарить за ответ

Comment: А не было ответа, так как было не ясно, каковы требования. Сейчас напишу ответ.

Comment: Если мой ответ помог вам решить проблему, отметьте ответ как решение и проголосуйте за ответ (см. [*Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?*](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
\b(?:0|\d{6}\s\d|(?:\d\s?)?\d+\s\d{3}|\d+)\b
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/ViTJwa/4).

**Подробности**

- `\b` - граница слова (сразу перед текущей позицией не должно быть буквы, цифры или знака `_`
- `(?:` - начало незахватывающей подмаски, используемой для того, чтобы границы слова были применимы ко всем шаблоном, перечисленным ниже

  - `0|` - ноль или
  - `\d{6}\s\d|` - шесть цифр (`\d{6}`), пробельный символ (`\s`), одна цифра (`\d`) или (`|`)
  - `(?:\d\s?)?\d+\s\d{3}|` - опциональная последовательность из одной цифры и необязательного пробельного символа (`(?:\d\s)?`), 1 и более цифр (`\d+`), пробельный символ и три цифры (`\d{3}`) или
  - `\d+` - 1 и более цифр
- `)` - конец незахватывающей подмаски
- `\b` - граница слова (сразу после текущей позиции не должно быть буквы, цифры или знака `_`.